# Java can't open file in CentOS 6.5

Tags: java, centos

I'm trying to run a java command prompt program that receives a path to a 5GB csv file.
While the path is guaranteed to be the right one and I'm running the program as root my program throws:

```
 (No such file or directory)ava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/tmp/NPPES/npidata.csv
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    ...
```

the java line is:

```
BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[1]));
```

the file listing:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root          4 Mar 11 15:35 empty.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5097950480 Feb 11 00:36 npidata.csv
```

Then I thought it might be the file size so I created a 4 character file. Still nothing.
Has anyone by any chance experienced this before?

**Update:**

I modified the java program to list all the receiving arguments and they displayed correctly.

I was running the program through a shell script launch.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
#echo on
java -Xmx16000M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -classpath "../classes:../lib/*" $@
```

When I ran it directly with java it worked: the file was found.

The greatest mistery is that the cmd line params displayed correctly in both situations.
I wonder if shell is actually adding some funny unseen chars to those params.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your file listing, only the root as the right to write on the file. Which means also that only the root can open it.

I think your application is not running as root so you should first try to change the right on your files :

> `chmod 666` This commande will allow everyone to read and write the files.

Sincerely,

Comment: I was running it as root and also I opened the file only for reading which is available for everyone. In the meantime I updated the question with new findings.